# Return a React's method 'return' as a string

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

I'm using the [Drop](https://github.com/HubSpot/drop) javascript library, and I get this error:

> Drop Error: Content function should return a string or HTMLElement.

I'm using React to handle a click, and then open the Drop popup.

```
popupContent: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
  )
},

initDrop: function() {
  var self = this;
  var drop = new Drop({
    target: self.refs.xxx,
    openOn: 'click',
    content: function() {
      self.popupContent();
    }
  });
},
```

---

How can I make the `popupContent` function return as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `String` from `popupContent` because now `popupContent` returns [`JSX`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) but `JSX` is not a `String`

```
popupContent: function() {
  return (
    '<div>' +
      '<p>Test.</p>' +
    '</div>'
  )
},
```

if you use ES2015 you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
popupContent: function() {
  return (
    `<div>
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>`
  )
},
```

also there is package [`jsx-to-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-to-string)(*note - you should install it*)

```
popupContent: function() {
  return jsxToString(
    <div>
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
  )
},
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32564/)